# Windows Store: how to test whether specific "metro" app is installed?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Well, the title says it all. From my Windows Store (a.k.a. "Metro") application, I need to know whether some other specific application is installed on that machine. Alternatively, I want to know whether there is some application that able to handle URL of specific theme (for me its the same problem) - without launching it.

I tried to use PackageManager from Windows.Management.Deployment namespace, but it not accessible from winrt...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.aspx

Is there any other way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any way to do it. If you want to invoke another app though - you can use a custom protocol with protocol activation to invoke an app that supports that protocol or have it installed from the store.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not answering my problem - I need to know whether there is some specific app installed and able to launch BEFORE trying to actually launching it (this decision affects my app UI).

Comment: It does answer your problem - "there isn't any way to do it".